# Default constructor call InterfaceConstructor with null

Tags: java

I try to do this:

```
public class Demo{
public Demo() {
    Demo(null)
}
public Demo(Interface myI) {
    ...
}
}
```

I would like the `Demo()` constructor to call the `Demo(Interface)` constructor with `null` however eclipse complains "Demo(null) is undefined" on the line where I call `Demo(null)`. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call a *method* called `Demo` which you haven't defined.

e.g.

```
class A {
   public A() {
      this(1); // calls constructor A(int)
      A(1); // calls method A(int)
   }
   public A(int i) {} // constructor A(int)
   public void A(int i) {} // method A(int)

   public A A(A a) { return a; } // method A(A) which returns A
}
```

If you want a constructor to call another you need to use `this()` like

```
public Demo() {
    this(null);
}
```

Comment: I had to read that twice to catch the difference between method and constructor in your first sentence, care to make it more obvious?

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up by example, though i find `public A A(A a)` highly confusing (what does the identity function help me here?). WIll accept once the timelimit elapses

Comment: Sometimes its is useful to have a copy constructor like `public A(A a)` which Java doesn't generate for you unlike C++, sometimes you need a function which will combine `this` with another of the same type e.g. `BigInteger` has a `public BigInteger add(BigInteger bi)` method. Calling a method the same name as the class is confusing and doesn't follow the Java Coding Convention of using `camelCase` for methods

Answer (score 8):

It shouldn't be `Demo(null)` but `this(null)`